# Getting java and flash to talk to each other

Tags: java, flash

I have an application written in java, and I want to add a flash front end to it. The flash front end will run on the same computer as the java app in the stand alone flash player. I need two way communication between the two parts, and have no idea how to even start going about this. I suppose I could open a  socket between the two programs, but I feel that there must be an easier way. Is there a nice part of the api in actionscript 3.0 that will allow me to access java methods directly, or will I have to resort to sockets? I am relatively new to flash, by the way, so any good guides would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) is a messaging protocol commonly used to talk between flash and a backend system. There're several Java implementations, but I haven't used any of them so can't tell you which is best.

- [Blaze DS](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/blazeds/)
- [Red5](http://www.osflash.org/red5)
- [Granite DS](http://www.graniteds.org/)

Flash can also talk plain old XML, SOAP or REST to the backend, so depending on your codebase that might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

There is also **[OpenAMF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openamf/)**.  It is *very* mature, stable, simple and lightweight relative to Blaze, Red5 and Granite.

**BUT**, it is also dated (AMF0 protocol only) and the project is no longer active.  Lots of people are still using it out in the wild.  And the documentation is borderline non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

Granite DS is a good solution, it will allow you to set up services to communicate not only to POJO's but to EJB3 session beans also. It comes with a GAS code generator for converting your java beans into as3 equivalents and also data push to the client using the gravity side project.

Answer (score 0):

MERAPI is a bridge framework for communication between Java and Flash.

Comment: Not really relevant yet.  It is for AIR applications, still in *private alpha* at the moment, and very unstable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree on Granite DS. It was easy to setup and get going.

I have used it to talk directly with a EJB3 bean communicating with thrift generated objects.