# How do you trigger events in a flash web application with java?

Tags: java, flash

How do you use java to trigger buttons and other inputs in a flash animation besides the robot class?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77598/getting-java-and-flash-to-talk-to-each-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If flash client is unaware of your Java backend, then there's no special way you could do it. There are some scripting environments that allow you to imitate keyboard and mouse input, like Xdotool, but there's nothing special to it and Java, it's just an external emulator tool with its own scripting language. Also note that Flash requires X-server (window-server) to run, so that if you need to run it on a headless server, this may be a bit of a problem...